# How to share cookie between domain and subdomain, but not other subdomains

Tags: asp.net, cookies, subdomain, iis-8

Our ASP.NET MVC web application has a few different subdomains we use for testing and legacy code. The subdomains are:

1. www.sitename.com (production site)
2. test.sitename.com (testing)
3. original.sitename.com (legacy code)
4. staging.sitename.com (occasionally used to testing right before a deployment)

We purposefully have the forms authentication not using domain level cookies because we want the cookies to be unique across these different subdomains. The problem is, when people get a link to the root domain (sitename.com), it requires them to log in again to get a cookie, even though they're already logged in to www.sitename.com.

Is there a way to share the cookie between *only* www.sitename.com and sitename.com without the other subdomains being affected?

Comment: you can redirect all sitename.com to www.sitename.com or vice versa to not to have this kind of problem.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend forcing the use of the www. version of the site, for this reason amongst others, this site has excellent reasons why...

http://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/

To do this in .net you can add the following to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sitename.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://www.{HTTP_HOST}{HTTP_URL}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
      </rule>
    </rules>
    <rewriteMaps>
      <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
        <add key="on" value="https" />
        <add key="off" value="http" />
      </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This will auto-redirect permanently (see the addition of redirectType="Permanent") for non-www URLs to the www equivalent and retain the HTTP(s) protocol.

The trackAllCaptures part is related to the regex pattern matching - in our case we do not need to capture anything; we only need to match for the rule, so we can leave as false.

The regex pattern ^sitename.com$ will match when the hostname matches exactly to "sitename.com" - the ^ means the start position and the $ means the end position

The rewrite map is from an idea from Jeff Graves I believe, http://jeffgraves.me/2012/11/06/maintain-protocol-in-url-rewrite-rules/

The way I have shown shows just one way to do this, like with most things - there are multiple ways on achieving this.

Scott Forsyth has an article on a different way of achieving this too (also references Jeff Graves)
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-rewrite-protocol-http-https-in-the-action

Comment: I notice that your answer differs from Ergun's in that your condition node has `trackAllCaptures="false"`. What's that all about?

Comment: trackAllCaptures is used for the regex to define whether the matching string should be included in the results indexes - you can find more details about it here http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Using_back-references_in_rewrite_rules - we're only matching for the host name and are not interesting in capturing anything so we can leave it as false

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid this problem by redirecting your non www domain to www with UrlRewrite module in >IIS7

rewrite rule to put into web.config

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}"
             redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but won't `pattern="^example.com$"` pick up, for instance, test.example.com?

Comment: "www" is an another subdomain and not different than test.example.com for this pattern. the pattern is correct for non subdomain address which is only "example.com"

Answer (score -1):

You can use some thing like

```
sessionCookie.Domain = ".yourdomain.com" ;
```

then you will be able to request same cookies from any subdomain and edit it if you want.

Comment: The answer is specifically asking for a way to not share the cookie across all subdomains, but only specific ones.